# Laravel grouping where clauses in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have created Eloquent query in laravel 5.4 in which I want to filter data through 6 different combination which are as follows:

1. Category
2. Subcategory
3. industry
4. style
5. orientation
6. color

**This is the query I have used**

```
 $updatedproducts  = Product::Where('category', $cat)
                     ->Where('subcategory', $subcat)
                     ->whereIn('industry', $industrytags)
                     ->orWhereIn('style', $styletags)
                     ->orWhereIn('orientation', $orientationtags)
                     ->orWhereIn('color', $colortags)
                     ->paginate(12);
```

Its working fine except one thing that category and subcategory is ignored when I fetch results from different category and subcategory I want data where category and subcategory should always match and other 4 remaining filter can be optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group as optional conditions:

```
$updatedproducts  = Product::Where('category', $cat)
                 ->Where('subcategory', $subcat)
                 ->where(function ($where) use ($industrytags, $styletags,  $orientationtags, $colortags) {
                    $where->whereIn('industry', $industrytags)
                        ->orWhereIn('style', $styletags)
                        ->orWhereIn('orientation', $orientationtags)
                        ->orWhereIn('color', $colortags);
                 })
                 ->paginate(12);
```

Comment: i also tried this but this also throws this error = Undefined variable: industrytags

Comment: Edited. Try again!

Answer (score 0):

Try your query in following way:

```
$updatedproducts  = Product::Where('category', $cat) 
            ->Where('subcategory', $subcat)
            ->where(function($q) use($industrytags ,$styletags, $orientationtags,$colortags) {
                $q->whereIn('industry', $industrytags)
                    ->orWhereIn('style', $styletags)
                    ->orWhereIn('orientation', $orientationtags)
                    ->orWhereIn('color', $colortags);
            })
            ->paginate(12);
```

it will always match for `category` && `subcategory` And other fields are optional.

Hope this will help

Comment: i tried this but its throwing this error  = Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Edited, semicolon was missing

Comment: now throwing this error = Undefined variable: industrytags